# Why am I getting "Invalid path for filesystem" when trying to commit in vs2013 using git?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Whenever I try to commit files in Visual studio 2013 using git integration, I keep getting this error:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: Invalid path for filesystem
>
> .../node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/got/node_modules/duplexify/node_modules/end-of-stream/node_modules/once/node_modules/wrappy/LICENSE': The data area passed to a system call is too small.

Using git commandline / git gui works fine, but not when trying to use VS2013 itself.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [known](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/865064) bug in VS2013. It has been fixed, starting from VS2013 update5. If you install VS2013 update5, the bug disappears, and you can use your visual studio to commit & push.

Comment: I have this bug again in VS2015 Update2. Any ideas?

Comment: Getting same issue for VS 2015. Do u have any idea?